# JS. Replace nested loop to standard Array API

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I had a case with comparing two arrays to getting user access to page:

```
let permitted = false;
const { authorities } = route.data;
const { roles } = user;
for (const role of roles) {
  for (const authority of authorities) {
    if (role.systemName === authority) {
      permitted = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

User has an array of `roles` and each `role` has field `systemName` is the value of an enum `UserType`.

`authorities` is array of `UserType` values directly.

```
export enum UserType {
  User = 'USER_ROLE',
  Admin = 'ADMIN_ROLE',
}
```

How to refactor this nested loops with standard array API like `some(...)`, `indexOf(...)` of JavaScript?

Comment: Maybe this should be closed and ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. By the way you didn't post any test cases.

Comment: how many usertypes and authorities are you expecting?

Comment: @Keith Nicholas not many now 3 in the future not more than 5

Comment: @aloisdg moving to codidact.com wow interesting, now we separate code review and development questions. I didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can do it with a nested `.some` (`O(n ^ 2)`), it would be more efficient to make a Set of one of the collections first, then use `.some` on the other (`O(n)`):

```
const { authorities } = route.data;
const { roles } = user;
const systemNames = new Set(roles.map(({ systemName }) => systemName));
const permitted = authorities.some(
  authority => systemNames.has(authority)
);
```